# Bash: sed regex pattern won't match strings

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed

I have tested this particular regex in RegExr.com:

```
/(\*)*((\s)?(\w)*)/g
```

to match the following:

```
* Global Links contained...etc
* Change User, contact list...etc
```

(everything from ... on is just extra words in the sentence, not a literal ...etc)

I tried to use this regex in a sed command as part of a bash script like so:

```
sed "/(\*)*((\s)?(\w)*)/d" test.txt > stripped.txt
```

But these two lines still remain in stripped.txt. Is there something I'm not accounting for in the regex or in the file? before these two lines is the start of a block comment (/**) and the block comment end is after them(*/), both of these are on new lines. Am i missing something obscure with new lines or is the sed command/regex wrong?

Comment: That `<` should be a `(`. Did you copy and paste the regex or is it a typo?

Comment: Just a typo, I have corrected this

Comment: Use `-r` for extended regex syntax (or escape the `(`, `)`, and `?`). But is that regex really what you want? It will match every line because everything in it matches empty strings.

Comment: So you basically want `/^\*.*/d`? (i.e. "any line that starts with a `*`)

Comment: Not neccessarily, this is a trivial script to strip out block comments from a css as a txt file, but there may be a rule such as * { //css stuff }

Comment: I see. Note that you are massively overusing parens in your expression. You don't need to group *everything* (in fact, you probably don't need to group anything at all). How about: `/\*\s*\w/d`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't accounting for the dialect of regex in use by sed by default.  That's not a valid BRE (basic regular expression).

You need to tell sed to use ERE's (extended regular expressions).

For GNU sed that is the `-r` flag and for BSD sed that is the `-E` flag (though `-r` is often available as a compat flag).

```
sed -r "/(\*)*((\s)?(\w)*)/d" test.txt > stripped.txt
```

Comment: Well in the words of Denzel Washington ala American Gangster - My Man.  Yet another case of not reading the documentation correctly, thank you

Comment: This answer in the Unix SE has a good explanation of the different regex syntaxes: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/119906/1199